# Get part of the url pathname via JavaScript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

I have following url:

```
https://www.example.com/article/f/1/test+article
```

And I need to get "1" part from the url via JavaScript (pure javascript). I know that I can get it with "location.pathname.replace()" but I'm not good with regex.

**UPDATE**

Just for clarification: "https://www.example.com/article/f/" never changes, it's constant. The only part of the url that can change is "1" (article id) and "test article" (article name). And I want to catch the article id.

Comment: Hi!  Please edit the question to be a little more specific.  Do you need to do this for **any** url?  Do you need to capture the right-most digit?  (For example, what if there are digits in the host name or in the article name)  Thanks!

Comment: Great place to learn regexes is https://www.debuggex.com/.

Comment: If you need a generic solution for any url, my answer is better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
location.pathname.match(/\/article\/f\/(\d+)/)[1]
```

I'm trying to match /article/f/ and at least 1 digit captured by the group(note the parenthesis).
If that id is the single number in your path, you can get it directly by:

```
location.pathname.match(/\d+/)[0]
```

Comment: This answer works for the sample url, but will break for `article/g` and will also break if the url has a number anywhere prior to the article number.

Comment: @Jess I agree, but it's a valid answer, explained and it's easy to modify it.

Comment: @МиленМихалев because someone considers my solution as too restrictive(i.e. it won't work for /article/g)

Answer (score 2):

This answer will get only the last `/number` expression in the url.

### Sample data:

```
https://www.example.com/article/f/1/test+article
http://www.aaa.com/2/thing/1
http://bbb.org/2anotherthing/1?a=b&c=b
```

### The regex:

`\/(\d+)\b(?!.*\/(\d+)\b)`

- `\/` Look for a slash
- `(\d+)` Capture group: get digits of any length
- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?!)` Negative look ahead.  Look ahead to makes sure we do not match the nested regex.
- `.*` Any characters.
- `\/(\d+)\b` The same regex again, so that we only match the right-most occurrence.

### The javascript:

Use javascript `exec` method to get the captured into an array called `cap`.

```
var cap = /\/(\d+)\b(?!.*\/(\d+)\b)/.exec("https://www.example.com/article/f/1/test+article");
```

Output is the full regex match and the captured group.

```
["/1", "1", undefined]
```

Then you can use `cap[1]` for the first captured group.

Comment: Why the down vote?  This is the most complete and robust answer.

Answer (score -1):

You know you can just match this with `\d`, right?

Is there some more specific pattern that you need to match?

Answer (score -1):

How about split path like:

```
var path = 'https://www.example.com/article/f/1/test+article';
var pathArray = path.split( '/' );
console.log(pathArray);
console.log(pathArray[5]);
```

### OUTPUT

```
["https:", "", "www.example.com", "article", "f", "1", "test+article"]
1
```

I've assumed you know at what 'index' (ie `/`) the `1` lies at, in your case the 6th (5th from base zero of course) index/element of the array

Comment: gwillie.  I'd encourage you to remove this answer.  It is a very brittle solution that will break if the url structure ever changes.  No offense.

Comment: @Jess I agree 100%, but that `1` in the url is positioned specifically. My answer was based on the fact that the OP knows what they are doing, and they knowingly have full knowledge of each url segment. If that wasn't the case then the OP is paddling up a steep inclined creek

Comment: at everybody: article id is *never* going to begin with 0.  All the answers on this page are wrong.

Comment: Not the best example, but part numbers can begin with zero in some contexts.  `www.compressedairpartscompany.com/0301-2121-01washeroematlascopco.aspx`

Comment: First, the OP has accepted an answer, regardless if it's right or wrong. Next, all answers are subjective, and based on what the OP provided in their initial question, and finally we, as those that answer, should not assume to much, ie make up what the OP is trying to do. We might see/have experience/know better, so all answers are right as it (hopefully) leads the OP down the road of self discovery. A lot of programming is trail and error, how often do you get it right 100% of the time, obviously that is was pun of sorts. There is no 100% right way ever, otherwise the world would be static :)