# Extracting the domain name from a URL using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I need a general script/pattern to extract the main domain name from URLs. I have the following attempt that failed.

Let use say I have this link1 and need to extract the main domain name (google.co.uk) without the sub-domain (mail). I made this script which worked fine with `.co.uk` but will fail with websites that has one top-level domain name like: `.com` and `.com`.

Is there a better way to extract main domain name from ANY URL? 
The URL is constructed as follows:

```
https://(optional sub-domain)*(domain name with two or three top-level domain name)(optional forward slash followed by text)*
```

The `*` refer to zero or more times.

```
var link1="https://mail.google.co.uk/link/link/link";
var url = new URL(link1);
var domain = url.hostname.split('.').slice(-3).join('.');
console.log("The domain name is: "+ domain);
```

In the above code, I expect: google.co.uk

It could work because the link has two parts in the top-level domain name (`.co.uk`) so `-3` works. But I need the code to work with this link as well:

```
var link1="https://mail.google.com/link/link/link";
```

And I need the output to be: `google.com`

But the problem is that the code produces:

```
mail.google.com
```

And  I only want the main domain name: `google.com`

**EDIT:**
Some of the expected output examples are here:

1) In `mail.google.co.uk` it should be: `google.co.uk`

2) In `mail.google.com` it should be: `google.com`

3) In `link.mail.google.com/link/link` it should be: `google.com`

4) In `link.link2.mail.google.com` it should be: `google.com`

i.e. just the main domain name without sub-domains or links after the domain name. The top-level domain name can be in the fom of (.com, .net, .org, etc.) or in the form of (.co.uk, .co.us, etc). The top-level domain name should be captured either if it is one part or two parts (my code capture only two parts).

Comment: what is the expected output of `domain` from link1?

Comment: @Nikola Lukic that link is to extract the top-level domain name. I am asking about the main domain name in addition to the top-level domain name. e.g. `google.com`, `google.co.uk`.

Comment: Problem for parsing i see with '.' and double dot.  You must make some validation object and define concrete roles. For example make this ".co.uk" like exception case . Program must know when is two or one dot valid result.

Comment: @Nikola Lukic  it is for any URL. I can not make exception. It is not only `.co.uk` but can be any thing. For example: `.co.us` or any other type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue while capturing Top-Level Domain from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40428687/issue-while-capturing-top-level-domain-from-url)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get part of the url pathname via JavaScript regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21481096/get-part-of-the-url-pathname-via-javascript-regex)

Comment: If you don't have a rule you can't make working script. Question is not bad but extra handling is needed.

Comment: I give you positive point to make this question a live . Suggestion make list of double case domain like 'co.uk'   - co. is one of the case.

Answer (score 0):

Sure if you wanted

```
"mail.google.co.uk"
```

you can just use

```
url.host
```

or if you wanted it with headers, use

```
url.origin
```

cheers!